# How do I create an abstract factory?

Tags: dart

Is it possible to somehow create an abstract factory method? Maybe what I'm trying to do is possible to implement differently?

```
abstract class ApiModel {
  // Error: A function body must be provided.
  factory ApiModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);
}

class User extends ApiModel {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  
  User({required this.id, required this.name});
  
  @override
  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json['id'] as int, 
      name: json['name'] as String,
    );
  }
}

class ApiResponse<Model extends ApiModel> {
  final List<Model> results;
  
  ApiResponse({required this.results});
  
  factory ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ApiResponse(results: (json['results'] as List).map((item) => Model.fromJson(item)).toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: An interface in Dart cannot dictate an implementor (or extender) to implement any specific static methods, constructors or factory constructors. It can only require the extender to call a constructor from the class it extends.

Comment: @julemand101 But how can I do what I wanted?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? I mean eventually you will have to create every .fromJson factory method separately, the json tags and member names will be different.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I find it difficult to explain this. This can be seen in the ApiResponse.fromJson method. Inheritance is required for a generic.

Comment: You cannot, in Dart, call static methods (or any kind of constructor) on a generic type or Type object.

Comment: For the abstract factory there is a workaround with passing types and using switch statement, but that does not solve the problem what the previous comment says, in `ApiResponse.fromJson` the `Model.fromJson` call will not work. See: https://dart.academy/creational-design-patterns-for-dart-and-flutter-factory-method/

Comment: I'd recommend not implementing your own JSON deserializer and just use an existing code-generation approach with [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) or [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
factory ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, Model Function(dynamic) mapper) {
    return ApiResponse(
        info: Info.fromJson(json['info']),
        results: (json['results'] as List).map(mapper).toList(),
    );
}
```